# Simpler "map" for structs in octave

Tags: octave

I have the following array of structs in octave:

`p=[struct('a',[1,2],'b',[3,4,5]),struct('a',[7,8,9],'b',[10,11])]`

Now I want to apply a function uniformly to them:

`arrayfun(@(x) x.b(1:2),p)`

But since octave does not infer that the expression `b(1:2)` yields uniform results, I get:

`error: arrayfun: all values must be scalars when UniformOutput = true`

Now I found the following workaround:

`reshape(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) x.b(1:2),p,"UniformOutput",false)),2,2)'`

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: what do you really want to do? You write "I want to apply a function uniformly to them" but all you do is indexing in your example. Btw, there is also `structfun`

Comment: I want to apply a function (which involves selecting a field from structs) to all elements of the array, like `map` in functional programming. `structfun` is not what I want, because this iterates over all fields. I want to select always the same field.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation:](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/arrayfun.html)

> If the parameter val after a further string input argument
>   "UniformOutput" is set true (the default), then the named function
>   func must return a single element which then will be concatenated into
>   the return value and is of type matrix.

Uniform output means sizes of input and output are same, not that all returned values are similar sized.

You can avoid reshape by sneaking the quote into different positions:

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) x.b(1:2)',p,"UniformOutput",false))
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) x.b(1:2),p,"UniformOutput",false)')
```

but the cell conversion step will stay. (Also, be careful with quote and complex numbers.)